# Web3 Contract Constructor Error

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle, blockchain

Currently getting this error in my Browser's Console:

[image]

My current set up is as follows:

```
Truffle v5.0.3 (core: 5.0.3)
Solidity - 0.5.0 (solc-js)
Node v8.9.4
```

Here's my code - and note that I'm using `.Contract` with a CAPITAL `C`, which I believe is the new, `Solidity - 0.5.0` way of doing this:

```
 App.MathContract = new web3.eth.Contract(
      [
        {
          "inputs": [],
          "payable": false,
          "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
          "type": "constructor"
        },
        ....
```

Interestingly, when I used the old syntax - `.contract` with a lower-case `c`, I do *not* get this error:

```
App.MathContract = App.web3Object.eth.contract(
      [
        {
          "inputs": [],
          "payable": false,
          "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
          "type": "constructor"
        },
        ....
```

Any thoughts about what I'm doing wrong? (I'll be happy to upload any other code that might fill in the gaps.)

============================================

UPDATE:

Here's what my `web3` version looks like:

[image]

Comment: Which version of web3 are you using in the browser? How web3 is initialized?

Comment: Could you please run `npm ls web3` and provide the printout?

Comment: Running `npm ls web3` yields `web3@1.0.0-beta.41`.   See updated question above - I provided a screengrab of this query.

Comment: Your description strongly implies that are using version 0.x. I believe that if you try to run your code directly with node (from a command line) instead of from your browser's console, then this error will not appear. If I'm right, then it means that your browser somehow relies on web3.js v0.x.

Comment: I think it might have something to do with the way `web3.min.js` is being imported - or NOT being imported into the project... I do have it in my `js` folder, which is inside my `src` folder, which is sitting inside my Project's folder - right alongside all the required folders (`migrations`, `contracts`, `node_modules`, etc.) - but I don't know if its getting read when running the project on `localhost:3000` (which is launched when I do `npm run dev`)

Comment: So how do I force `localhost:3000` to find and use the right version of `web3`?   I'm asking because I went ahead and added a `console.log` statement to display the version of `web3` that's being used during run-time, and Chrome's console is saying its `0.20.3` - which is NOT what I have installed in my project's folder.  But since I'm serving my HTML DApp from `localhost:3000`, its using some different path, and that path seems to have the old version of `web3.min.js`

Comment: Side note: inside your JS code, you can check web3 version, and then choose whether to use `contract` or `new Contract` accordingly.

Comment: that's not a bad idea - but I kinda wanna do this the "right" way, know what I mean?